# Veracode issue in JSP - Insertion of Sensitive Information Into Sent Data (CWE ID 201)

Tags: java, jsp, veracode

Following is the piece of code

`<jsp:useBean id="test1" scope="session" class="java.lang.String" />`

`<%=test1%>`

In the line "<%=test1%>" I am getting the vera code issue . How to fix the issue.

Tried to fix with below code, It is showing another issue "Improper Handling of Invalid Use of Special Elements (CWE ID 159)"
`<%= ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(test1) %>`